# function not returning string with unique characters

Tags: python-3.x, string, duplicates

```
def dup(str):
  str1=""
  for ch in str:
    if ch not in str1:
        print(ch)
        str1 = str1+ch
    return(str1)
```

why am I not getting duplicate free string, I am getting the original string

I am trying to return string with unique characters, but I am getting original string

Comment: *"but I am getting original string"* - No you're not.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's an indentation problem. Your `return` statement is indented so that it sits within the `for` loop. The function will return only the first character because the return is encountered right after adding the first character to `str1`. Move it back one level of indentation and it should work correctly.

Caution: `str` is also the name of the Python string object type. To avoid confusion you might want to choose another variable name, for example:

```py
def dup(st):
  st1=""
  for ch in st:
    if ch not in st1:
        print(ch)
        st1 = st1 + ch
  return st1
```

Answer (score 0):

You got something wrong with the Tabbing-Syntax from Python. You put your `return(str1)` into the `for` loop, which returns the `ch` which is a char of the string. Since you want the whole string to return you need to put the return statement out of the loop.

```py
def dup(str):
    str1 = ""
    for ch in str:
        if ch not in str1:
            print(ch)
            str1 = str1 + ch
    return (str1)
```

The loop only runs once and then immediately returns the string which causes the function to quit since you already returned something. The code I provided above should work.